# HTML5 video not working on chrome,IE after hosting on server, video in mov file (quicktime format)

Tags: javascript, css, html, sharepoint, video

In our teamVideo.html page, we are using HTML5 video tag to show video. Video file is in .mov format( quicktime format) shot using iphone.

```
<video preload="none">
<source src="video/v1.mov">
</video>
```

if teamVideo.html is opened directly in browser(chorme,IE9), page works properly, video plays properly.

After hosting this page to sharepoint site, video is not working. chrome shows just black color video box, nothing happening on play. IE shows, like image not found box.
In developer tools, i can see video file is getting requested &  downloaded with 200 ok status.If I open video url in new tab, video get downloaded properly.

If I specify type="video/quicktime" in video tag, even local video does n't work

```
<video preload="none">
<source src="video/v1.mov" type="video/quicktime">
</video>
```

If I specify type "video/mp4", even tough file is .mov type, it work on local , but doesn't work when hosted on server.

```
<video preload="none">
<source src="video/v1.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I tried to use .mp4 file instead of .mov file, but this is also not working after hosting. I found that, sharepoint server is issueing mime type "application/octate-stream" for .mp4 file & may be this is causing problem for video tag.

Can anyone suggest, what could be issue & how to resolve this.

Comment: Please do update the question whenever you find an update.

Answer (score 0):

Use browser tools to check whether the server is actually returning a valid response and if not check the error message in your server logs in IIS (if necessary turn on Request tracing).

If the server is IIS make sure the mime type for each of the file extensions is set up and configured. Without a matching mime type IIS will return a 404.

Comment: I have check network traffic in developer tool n in fiddler , video file is getting requested and request is complete with 200 OK status.content type for .mov file is coming as "video/QuickTime". Is " video/QuickTime" is supperted by HTML5 video?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a website deployed to Azure.  I could not use any file type mp4, ogg or webm on my HTML5 video.  I put the following in my Web.config file of my project in Visual Studio and it worked.  Azure was not recognizing the mime types.  Credit to Alex Titarenko (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2898722/alex-titarenko) for cluing me on this.

```
<system.webServer>

<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
</staticContent>


</system.webServer>
```